# Differences in the appearance of the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-8

What causes the difference in the appearance of a table run from the project and directly from the file?

This is appearance of a table run directly from the file with command key (shift + F6)

[image: this is appearance of a table run directly from the file]

This is appearance of a table run from project with command key (F6)

[image: this is appearance of a table run from project]

For your information I used Netbeans 8.2 IDE.

Comment: I'd say the PLAF for starters. *"For your information I used Netbeans 8.2 IDE."* My condolences. (Assuming the IDE is actually relevant to this difference.)

Comment: Different Java version maybe? (PLAF means "Platform Look & Feel")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name *"(PLAF means "Platform Look & Feel")"* The P is for Pluggable.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/UIManager.html